# Custom Projection for Photogrammetry and 3D Modeling

Tags: 3d, coordinate-system

We are an animation company specializing in infrastructure and urban design.  We get lots of data from engineers and GIS agencies in various state plane coordinate systems.  Often the coordinates are very large numbers which 3D animation packages and game engines will truncate because most use a fixed numbers of decimals to store values.

To put Portland, Oregon somewhere close to 0,0 in 3D Studio Max, we translate all of our local data in NAD 83 Oregon State Plane North (HARN) by the following:

```
X: -7645805.0
Y:  -683955.0
```

As we get into photogrammetry, we're looking at more data that is geolocated in state plane.  It would be great if we could translate data to our the coordinates directly in the apps (Pix4D, Reality Capture, qGIS, ArcGIS) using a custom projection.

Can anyone suggest how we could modify NAD 83 Oregon State Plane North (HARN) to move 0, 0 to -7,645,805.0,  -683,955.0?

Comment: Look for the false easting and northing in your projection file, if you edit these numbers your data should 'move'... alternately create your own 'my_State_Plane' projection file and warp your data to it. I would use ArcGIS to do this, it has a handy *roll your own* projection dialog allowing you to save it to a list for use later.